# Weird File type when trying to share widget screenshot in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-image

I am trying to use the Flutter [Screenshot package](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) with the [Share Plus package](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) to share images of widgets.

I finally thought I got it all working, but when I tested it I got this:

[image]

That doesn't look like an image filetype to me. Here is what I am doing with both packages:

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () async {
              final imageFile = await screenshotController.capture();
              XFile file = XFile.fromData(imageFile!);
              Share.shareXFiles([file]);
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
            label: const Text("Share Image"),
          ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, the `screenshotController.capture()` will return an `Uint8List image` type, that why XFile treats it as a binary kind as expected. I suggest that you save the image first then upload it.

```
_screenshotController.capture().then((Uint8List image) async {
  if (image != null) {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final imagePath = await File('${directory.path}/image.png').create();
    await imagePath.writeAsBytes(image);

    /// Share Plugin
    await Share.shareFiles([XFile(imagePath)]);
  }
});
```

Comment: ShareFiles doesnt exist anymore its shareXFiles now. Which keeps tripping me up. If I try your code I get: The element type 'String' can't be assigned to the list type 'XFile'.

Comment: Sorry long time no see the library. I have updated the pseudo code. The concept is to convert `Uint8List` byte array to image then convert it to `XFile` to pass into the SharePlus. 
I am not sure if the `XFile` can be constructed from `Uint8List `. If yes, then no need to convert it into a temp image like pseudo code. You check it to optimize but the idea is still there.